# React can't read property. Is it wrong binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind, jsx

I am trying to build an order list/form with React.
But, after clicking one of products an error occurs:

> Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

```
  13 | totalSum() {
  14 |  this.setState({
> 15 |      total: this.state.total + this.product.price
  16 |  })
  17 | }
```

Is it wrong binding in constructor ? If yes, could you explain me why?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Summary from './summary';

class ShoppingCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            total: 0
        }
        this.totalSum = this.totalSum.bind(this);
    }

    totalSum() {
        this.setState = {
            total: this.state.total + this.product.price
        }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
            products.map((product) => {
                return (
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick={this.totalSum.bind(this)}>{product.name} {product.price}$</li>
                    </ul>
                );
            })
        }
        <Summary totalSum={this.totalSum}></Summary>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var products = [
    {
        name: "Product 1",
        price: 250
    },
    {
        name: "Product 2",
        price: 70
    },
    {
        name: "Product 3",
        price: 140
    },
    {
        name: "Product 4",
        price: 640
    },
    {
        name: "Product 5",
        proce: 290
    },
]
export default ShoppingCard;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `this.product` in your case. Did you mean `this.props.product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is a function and not a variable to which you assign a value

Also `this.product` is not defined in your code, you need to pass the price to `totalSum` function from the map function like

```
 totalSum(price) {
    this.setState({
        total: this.state.total + price
    })
 }
```

render function:

```
 <div>
    {
        products.map((product) => {
            return (
                <ul>
                    <li onClick={this.totalSum.bind(this, product.price)}>{product.name} {product.price}$</li>
                </ul>
            );
        })
    }
    <Summary totalSum={this.totalSum}></Summary>
  </div>
```

**P.S.** Also I don't see `products` defined in your map function, I suppose you have defined it before using it.